# I am trying to select data from 2 mysql tables into 1 query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 mysql tables,

1st table holds data about files (including a folder id)

2nd table holds data about folders

I want to select the files per user, and i also need to include the folder name, which is held in the second table.

So i need to join these tables somehow.

#### table 1 - files

```
`file_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
`FILE_NAME` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`FILE_SIZE` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`FILE_TYPE` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`file_added` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`share_type` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`folder_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
`u_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

#### table 2 - folders

```
`folder_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`folder_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`u_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

So i need to be able to select: file_name(table1), file_size(table1), folder_name(table2)

I've tried a lot of things, like this foe example:

```
SELECT files.file_name, files.file_size, folders.folder_name 
FROM files
  JOIN folders ON files.u_id = folders.u_id
WHERE 
  files.u_id = ?
  AND folders.u_id = ?
ORDER BY folders.folder_name, files.file_name
```

but that just returns multiple rows of the files with each folder name at the end

How far wrong am i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The joining column between your two tables relates them via the `folder_id`, not `u_id` (which I assume has to do with user ownership).

The `WHERE` clause in your query may be unnecessary, an artifact of attempting to use an implicit join.  For now, remove the `WHERE` clause entirely and correct the join `ON` condition.  Using `WHERE` conditions to relate two tables is done when an old-style implicit join is used (comma-separated tables in the `FROM` clause) but that does not appear to be what you are doing here.

In any case, an explicit `JOIN` is the modern, preferred syntax.

Add back any `WHERE` clause you need to limit your results to a filtered set.

```
SELECT
  files.file_name,
  files.file_size,
  folders.folder_name 
FROM
  files
  JOIN folders ON files.folder_id = folders.folder_id
ORDER BY
  folders.folder_name,
  files.file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Since its a pretty straight forward query. I would not bother with the JOIN syntax. INNER en OUTER JOINS have there place. But here, a file always has a folder (i assume).

```
SELECT 
    A.file_name, A.file_size, B.folder_name 
FROM 
    files A, folders B 
WHERE A.folder_id = B.folder_id
```

A & B are table aliases

Answer (score 0):

You should join tables using folder_id field. Try this variant:

```
SELECT files.file_name, files.file_size, folders.folder_name 
FROM files
  JOIN folders ON files.folder_id = folders.folder_id AND files.u_id = ? ORDER BY folders.folder_name, files.file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT files.file_name, files.file_size, folders.folder_name 
    FROM files 
    INNER JOIN folders ON files.u_id = folders.u_id AND files.FOLDER_ID = folders.Folder_ID 
    ORDER BY folders.folder_name, files.file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select files.*, folders.folder_name from files join folders on folders.folder_id = files.folder_id where files.u_id = USERID
```